# When should the AC resistance of a diode be taken into account in a practical circuit?

Tags: ac, diodes, small-signal

In many circuit design examples I see the diode drop is taken constant value such as 700mV. And I also know that for amplification and small signals transistors are used as discrete components.

[Here](http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee320/notes/320Lecture4.pdf) AC resistance is explained under the name of "Small-Signal Diode Model and Its Application". Yes I can understand the math behind the AC resistance of the diode here. But what is the application here? I mean maybe SPICE programs take care of the AC resistance of diodes, but when one designs a circuit does he really take this into account?

I'm wondering when can the knowledge of AC resistance of a diode comes into scene in a practical circuit design. When would you need to consider this when you have pen and paper and a circuit in mind? What can be the examples?

**edit:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diode can be represented by the series connection of a fixed voltage source \$V_{T0}\$ in series with a dynamic resistance \$r_d\$. The source level depends on the technology: around 0.6 V for a silicon diode and 0.4 V for a Schottky diode. The below picture shows you this equivalent model:

[image]

You can see that the total drop label \$V_f\$ is the sum of \$V_{T0}\$ and the resistive drop. The dynamic resistance is determined by calculating the slope at the diode dc operating point. Obviously, when a current flows in this structure, it incurs power dissipation. The formula describing these conduction losses are as follows: \$P_d=V_{T0}I_{d,avg}+r_dI^2_{d,rms}\$. The first contributor is the average current while the second is the rms current. If the current flowing in the diode has a weak ac component (not much ripple around the dc value), then the formula \$P_d\approx V_fI_{d,avg}\$ gives good results. However, if the current contains a strong ripple, like in a heavy discontinuous mode-operated switching converter, then you must account for the diode dynamic resistance for power computation.

Comment: This is great explanation. Could you also explain a bit more in detail why the first contributor is the average current while the second is the rms current? Isnt active power always equal to Vrms*Irms?

Comment: The average power is the integration of the instantaneous power \$p(t)=i(t)\times v(t)\$ over a period. If \$v(t)\$ is constant and equal to \$V_{T0}\$, it becomes a factor multiplied by the average current \$I_{d,avg}\$. Same if you want the average power delivered by a dc source, it is the source constant voltage multiplied by the average current it delivers. For the second term, it is a resistance so the power is proportional to the squared rms current.

Answer (score 0):

The "AC resistance" of ideal silicon diode is 0.026 / I_amps. At 1mA, the AC resistance (the slope) is 26 ohms. At 1uA, the slop is 26,000 ohms.

At high currents in a real diode, the extra silicon needed to connect to the junction causes a LINEAR RESISTANCE to appear in the model, thus linearizing
the behavior at high currents.

The exact same math provides the slope, the gm, the transconductance, of the bipolar transistor. The gain of a bipolar stage, with no added emitter impedance, is thus gm * Rcollector, where Rcollector includes **all** resistances and impedances connected to the collector node.

Answer (score 0):

> when can the knowledge of AC resistance of a diode comes into scene in
>   a practical circuit design

It depends on the operating range of the circuit. For instance, if we have a circuit as shown below:

[image]

Then here we are operating diode through all of its on and off regions (because the voltage V2 can be both positive and negative), the circuit is a half wave rectifier, and we cannot use the incremental or AC resistance model.
But if the same circuit is run with a DC bias voltage and a small or incremental sinusoid around the bias voltage then incremental analysis makes sense and we can replace the resistor with its equivalent AC resistance.
Thus in summary it all depends on the operating range of the circuit.